# Reposition draggable modal every time modal is opened Discussions

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a draggable modal window and users move it around. They want it to open at the original position, every time they close the window and reopen again. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bootstrap modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

**show.bs.modal** This event fires immediately when the `show` instance method is called. If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the `relatedTarget` property of the event.

by default the bootstrap modal slide-down from top and if position of modal changes while dragging, it can be rest to original position with `show.bs.modal` when close and re-open next time.

```
$('selector').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
  // do something...
});
```

[Demo Fiddle modal slide and open in middle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6gd0jtxb/)

In above fiddle, added a custom position to modal so modal slide and open in middle of the page

```
.modalnewposition {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-0%) translateY(25%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-0%) translateY(25%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-0%) translateY(25%);
    transform: translateX(-0%) translateY(25%);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade modalnewposition" role="dialog">
```

Then created another class

```
.original {
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out 0s;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s;
}
```

Using `show.bs.modal` I added the `original` selector to modal so it adjust it's position before showing and override the `modalnewposition` selector so modal slide and open at top instead in middle of page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.modal').addClass("original");
    });
});
```

[Demo Fiddle modal slide and open at top](http://fiddle.jshell.net/6gd0jtxb/1/)

Above example is just to demonstrate that what you asked is achievable with `show.bs.modal` function.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to js and execute it every time modal window closes:

```
var scrollableContentOfModal = document.getElementById(...);// change it accordingly

document.querySelector(scrollableContentOfModal).scrollTop = 0;
```